# Uneven Columns using CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This problem references this page: [2-Column Team Page](http://anicon2a.anicondev.com/?page_id=686)

**NOTE: I had to remove some links because I am new to this site.  Please look at the sample page.**

I am using WordPress 3.5.1 and the Poloray theme.

I am creating a page of partners in my organization.  The design calls for 2 columns: the left column has an image and the right column has an excerpt from the individual's bio page.  Mousing over the image displays contact info (this works fine).

I have tried for several days to implement code that produced 2-columns within a theme .  When I create one left/right column pair everything lines up.  But once I replicate the code for the next person the second bio excerpt is pushed way down.

The code I found is:

```
 <style><!--#columns { width: 600px; }  #columns .column { position: relative; width: 46%; padding: 1%;  }  #columns .left { float: left; width: 30%; padding: 1%;  }  #columns .right
```

{ float: right; width: 65%; padding: 1%;  }-->

```
<p style="text-align: left;"><strong>Leadership</strong></p>
<p>
<div id="columns">
<div class="left column"><figure><a href="http://anicon2a.anicondev.com//?page_id=467 "><img class="alignnone" title="Vishal  415-894-5509 | vishal@anicon-group.com" alt="Vishal-Resume-Photo" src="**IMAGE LINK**" width="70" height="70" /></a>
<figcaption>Vishal Parikh</figcaption></figure></div>
<div class="right column">Ex prompta apeirian nam, vix an rebum partem. Has pertinax gubergren necessitatibus eu, tamquam accommodare concludaturque eu eumsed cu...
<a href="**BIO PAGE LINK**">Learn more about Vishal</a></div>
</p>
<p>
<div class="column"><figure><a href="**BIO PAGE LINK**"><img class="alignnone" title="Richard 415-894-5255 | richard@anicon-group.com" alt="Richard Targett" src="**IMAGE LINK**" width="70" height="70" /></a>
<figcaption>Richard Targett</figcaption></figure></div>
<div class="right column">Rick has more than 20 years of experience leading efforts in financial services and entrepreneurial ventures including 12 years in capital markets with a global Wall Street investment banking firm, 10 years in senior role for a big 4 firm...
<a href="http://anicon2a.anicondev.com/?page_id=473">Learn more about Rick</a></div>
</p>
```

The divs repeat for each person.  I have played with the widths, position (relative vs. absolute), making the second div start with the ".column" class vs. "left-column".  Nothing seems to work.

This solution is the closest to giving me the desired effect.  I tried other approaches using the `<li>` tag but the results were worse.

Comment: Please structure the code and make sure that all the lines have at least four spaces at the beginning to be displayed properly. Moreover a minimal example leads to more answers since it's hard to understand unstructured and blown code.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap every left and right content with an element with a class say `column-wrap` i.e `.left` and `.right` elements will be wrapped with `column-wrap`. Repeat the `.column-wrap` block. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zVJfB/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="columns">
    <div class="column-wrap">
        <div class="left column">
          <!--left content-->
        </div>
        <div class="right column"> 
          <!--right content-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column-wrap">
        <div class="left column">
          <!--left content-->
        </div>
        <div class="right column"> 
          <!--right content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#columns .column-wrap {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```